# How can I prevent my hidden folder from coming up in Windows 10 search?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

I have a hidden folder at C:\Users\me\hidden. It contains a (non-hidden) file called hidden_file.txt. When I type hidden_file.txt in the OS search, the file is the first result.

Is there any way to make that file not show up?

Comment: It would require you to change the permissions on the contents of the folder, so you can't actually view the contents, but if you can add these permissions back so can everyone else.  What practical problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

[You can exclude specific folders from Search (AKA "Cortana").](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-tms/how-do-exclude-folders-from-windows-search/58f845f6-d6fa-449e-a921-52be453038f1)

That said, it can still be found by exhaustive search tools if someone is looking.